# Build criteria query to fetch keys with db function jsonb_object_keys() : getting NullPointer exception

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I want to build criteria query which fetches distinct keys from the jsonb column :
select distinct jsonb_object_keys(tags) from tableView where condition;

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<String> query = cb.createQuery(String.class);
    Root<TableView> root = query.from(Table.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
      Expression<String> keysOfTags = cb.function("jsonb_object_keys", String.class,                      root.get(Constants.TAGS));
      query.select(keysOfTags).distinct(true);
      predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(Constants.TYPE), Type));

      Predicate[] predicatesArr = predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
      query.where(predicatesArr);
      Query createQuery = em.createQuery(query);
      List<String> keys = createQuery.getResultList();
```

I tried the above code, but I'm getting `NullPointer` at line:

```
Query createQuery = em.createQuery(query);
```